# jQuery appended inputs doesn't send value to Laravel controller

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, append, undefined

This is my jQuery function for appending new input fields. But after sending data, I always receive only the first inputs value in the request array.

```
  var count = 1;
  $("#delete_button0").hide();

   $(document).on('click', '#add_button', function () {
      $(this).remove();
      var newLink='';
      var lastCount = count - 1;  
        newLink +=  '<div class="row">'+
                      '<div class="form-group col-lg-8">'+                
                        '<input type="text" name="qwerty[]" class="form-control">'+
                      '</div>'+ 
                      
                      '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '<button type="button" id="add_button" name="add_button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary addtask float-right">'+
                        '<i id="button_icon" class="fa fa-plus"></i>'+
                        '<button type="button" id="delete_button'+count+'" name="delete_button'+count+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger addtask float-right">'+ 
                        '<i id="button_icon" class="fa fa-minus"></i>'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
        
        $("#linkbuilder").append(newLink);

        $("#delete_button" + count).hide();
        $("#delete_button" + lastCount).show();
        count++;
    })
```

This is my Html code where I am appending new inputs

```
 <div id="linkbuilder"> 
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-8">                
                      <input type="text" name="qwerty[]" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <button type="button" id="add_button" name="add_button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary addtask float-right"> 
                      <i id="button_icon" class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                      <button type="button" id="delete_button0" name="delete_button0" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger addtask float-right"> 
                      <i id="button_icon" class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
```

Can't understand the reason why I don't get the values from the inputs which I have appended.

Comment: The html you are building seems wrong. You open `<button>` but don't close it `</button>`. Also , where are you checking if the inputs have appended?

Comment: There is no problem with buttons, they are working perfectly. The only problem is that appended inputs values aren't sending to the controller. About inputs, I have a display function for them, so they are appending perfectly too.

Comment: Allright, then maybe it would be usefull to see the complete form's html to it is easy to replicate :) Can you send a form's html with all the extra inputs already generated? That would greatly help with testing what is happening :)

Comment: The whole form is huge this is a little part of it :)

Comment: I would do a doublecheck on the html structure(paste it into https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html). if the structure does not pass, it might be the problem

Comment: Strange thing is that when I copy-paste the same HTML as the first one, it returns the whole array in the request. But with append, it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem was <form> placement, found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976055/php-post-not-getting-the-html-input-element-value-which-append-by-jquery

Comment: Nice, so actually posting the whole form wasn't such a bad idea after all. Lucky it is resolved

Comment: Yes after you answer had a good look at the form, it helped me a lot thanks :)